# Laravel pagination security

Tags: laravel, validation, eloquent, pagination

**Do I need to validate the pagination parameters (*page, perPage*..)??**

- while writing some code with Laravel api I searched if there is any validation via Laravel code but it does not exists!!
  so do I need to take care of it?

```
public function index(PaginationRequest $request){
....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

literally, you don't need any validation for pagination. But when you call the pagination and per page variable kindly add some default value. So that you cannot face any error.

Comment: Thanks
-
is there any validation for these attributes??